# Remove a part of a tag in php

Tags: php, html, tags, attributes, strip

I want to remove tags from php to show this results:

Before:

```
1: <span class="n n21" title="Germania">&nbsp;</span>
2: <a href="/team/34?hl=it-IT" title="FC Schalke 04"><img data-src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png" class="list-mini" src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png"></a>
```

After

```
1: Germania
2: FC Schalke 04
```

Any helps? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the 1: and 2: line numbers or are they included in the string? We need some more information, where do you get the string, is it static ...

Comment: you can try this `preg_replace('@(\d+: ).*title="([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)".*@i', '$1$2', $text)` or `preg_replace('@(\d+: ).*title="([^"]+)".*@i', '$1$2', $text)`

Comment: yes, they are included in a string.

Comment: thank you @anonymous for your answer, i don't know how to use the first and the second part of preg_replace --> '@(\d+: ).*title="([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)".*@i', '$1$2'  -- i search on the internet but i don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are static strings then a regex should work but if you are reading from a webpage somewhere on the interwebs I would suggest using DOMDocument.

As you are reading the data as a string this might be of interest? It doesn't remove anything from the string data - just finds the element attributes that you are looking for and echoes them back.

```
            $data='
            <span class="n n21" title="Great Britain">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="n n21" title="Germania">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="n n21" title="france">&nbsp;</span>
            <a href="/team/34?hl=it-IT" title="FC Schalke 04"><img data-src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png" class="list-mini" src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png"></a>
            <a href="/team/35?hl=it-IT" title="Porto"><img data-src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/35.png" class="list-mini" src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png"></a>
            <a href="/team/36?hl=it-IT" title="England"><img data-src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png" class="list-mini" src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png"></a>';


            libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
            $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
            $dom->validateOnParse=false;
            $dom->standalone=true;
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
            $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
            $dom->substituteEntities=false;
            $dom->recover=true;
            $dom->formatOutput=true;

            $dom->loadHTML( $data );

            $parse_errs=serialize( libxml_get_last_error() );
            libxml_clear_errors();

            /* get titles from SPAN elements */
            $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
            foreach( $col as $node ) echo $node->getAttribute('title').'<br />';
            /* Get titles from A tags */
            $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach( $col as $node ) echo $node->getAttribute('title').'<br />';

            $dom=null;
```

Comment: using CURL in c++ i download all the source code in a txt file, than using php i insert all that in a string. i don't know which of them i can use.

Comment: okey, these seem to be work.
If i have another <span> or <a> that they must not be displayed and some random text (outside the tags) that has to be displayed?
example:

<a href="/players?hl=it-IT&na[]=51"><span class="n n51" title="**Serbia**">&nbsp;</span></a> <span class="p plt p76"> **76** </span><span class="p prt p86"> **86** </span> <a href="/player/215716?hl=it-IT" title="Aleksandar Mitrović"> **A. Mitrović** </a> **19** <a href="/team/229?hl=it-IT" title="**Anderlecht**"></a> **4.4k**

All that in Bold has to be displayed. 
thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) can help you.

```
$html = '<span class="n n21" title="Germania">&nbsp;</span>';
$pattern = '/title="(.+)"/';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $match);

print $match[1];
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/uL1cW1/1) here

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
preg_replace('#<span.*?\s+title="([^"]+)">&nbsp;.*?<a\s+.*?title="([^"]+)"><img#sui', "$1\n$2", text);
echo nl2br($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

In every string take starting digits and value of title attribute

```
$str = '1: <span class="n n21" title="Germania">&nbsp;</span>
2: <a href="/team/34?hl=it-IT" title="FC Schalke 04"><img data-src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png" class="list-mini" src="http://2015.sofifa.org/15/teams/24/34.png"></a>';

$str = preg_replace('/^(\d+:\s).+\stitle=\"([^\"]+)\".+$/m', '\1\2', $str);
```

echo $str;

result

```
1: Germania
2: FC Schalke 04
```

Comment: if i have also to display a word between <span> and <a>. so the result  will be
1: Germania
  random word (between the 2 tags)
2: FC Shalke 04

Comment: Change there string as you want https://eval.in/405687 And give the link with incorrect result

Comment: 1st - your input not contain line numbers. 2nd - you "ATT" not matching rules described before